# Elasticsearch: When just filtering, why use the filtered query type

Tags: elasticsearch

What's the difference between

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
    "filter": { "term": { "folder": "inbox" } }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": { "folder": "inbox" }
  }
}
```

It seems they both filter the index on the `folder` field by the `inbox` value.

Comment: For which elasticsearch version? `filtered` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can have two type of context in elastic search. `Query` context and `filter` context. Query context tells how well a document matches the query i.e. it calculates score whereas filter context tells whether a document matches the query and no scoring is done.

A query in query context tell you which document better matches the query. Higher the score more relevant the document is.

A query in filter context behaves like a conditional operator i.e. **true** if document matches the query and **false** if it doesn't.

To answer your question, both the queries will match the same number of documents but first query will not calculate the score (it will be faster compared to the second one because score calculation is skipped), whereas the second one will calculate score and will be slower comparatively to the first one. So if you just want to filter it is better to tell elastic that score need not to be calculated by putting the query in filter context. This way you save the computational cost of calculating score. Calculating score will be an overhead if only filtering is required and hence there are two type of contexts.

Sample output for 1st query (filter context):

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "3",
  "_score": 0,                 <-------- no scoring done
}
```

Sample output for 2nd query (query context):

```
{
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "2",
  "_score": 0.9808292          <-------- score calculated
}
```

So use query context to get relevant matches and filter context to filter out documents. You can use the combination of both as well.

You can read more on query and filter context [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what is said upstairs, but there is one thing to add.*Query* and *Filter* can be used together in a query to reduce time.